# How to get particular json object in from a nested json object which is dynamic based on particular path given which also dynamic

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

In my application, we have a method that accepts JSON and path which tell us which object we need to get from that JSON. Buth both JSON and path are dynamic, I can't predict that every time we get a request we are getting the same JSON and path.
Example:

```
{  
    "company": {  
        "employees": {  
            "employee": {  
                "department": {  
                    "departmentId": 1,  
                    "departmentName": "Developer"  
                },   
                "employeeDetails": {  
                    "id": 1,  
                    "name": "abc"  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

and the path is company.employees.employee.department. And the requirement is when I get this path I only need that nested JSON object with employee details. 
 Expected output:
{

```
"company": {  
        "employees": {  
            "employee": {  
                "department": {  
                    "departmentId": 1,  
                    "departmentName": "Developer"  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about your requirement. There is ambiguity in your question. I am thinking that you want to access employeeDetails from the JSON. Here is the solution for that:

```js
var data = {  
    "company": {  
        "employees": {  
            "employee": {  
                "department": {  
                    "departmentId": 1,  
                    "departmentName": "Developer"  
                },   
                "employeeDetails": {  
                    "id": 1,  
                    "name": "abc"  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}


var employee = data.company.employees.employee // this will store the nested json which is having employeeDetails

console.log(employee)// nested JSON with employeeDetails
console.log(employee.employeeDetails)// this will give you the employeeDetails
```

Comment: Requirement is I need JSON based on path given from original json

Answer (score 0):

The method may look like:

```js
const getData = (json, path) => {
  let current = json;
  const keys = path.split('.');
  for (let key of keys) {
    if (!current) {
      break;
    }
    current = current[key];
  }
  return current;  
};

getData(yourJSON, 'key1.key2.key3');
```